# would you use sculpt brushes to create neck tendons on male

Tags: modeling

I am creating male neck. Making neck tendons with verts distorts model. Will sculpt brushes do it?
If so, do you simply paint over the tube mesh?

Comment: What is your question? Model base mesh with good topology first, then either add Multires modifier or enable dyntopo and progressively increase level of details. Any details are often done in sculpting

Comment: thanks -   all that is beyond me. but i keep for when i can understand it XD

Comment: Watch some sculpting tutorials before proceeding further, look how does the base mesh look they use for sculpting. The main idea of my comment was that details like tendons are sculpted.